# Incorrect alignment of text in PDF field with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to compile a PDF form programmatically with Java, using PDFBox 1.8.16.

My workflow has been the following:

1. I exported my design with InDesign as a PDF form with named fields
2. I wrote a Java script that parses a CSV and compile the form programmatically

The problem I'm getting is on the alignment of the text inside the field, after the completion. As you can see, the image aligns to the bottom of the text field.

[image: Wrong text alignment]

The strange behavior I'm getting is when I select the field just like I'd do to edit the content: when I do that, the text aligns correctly.

[image: Correct text alignment]

The code I'm using to fill the text field is:

```
private void setField(String fieldName, String content, String fontName, Boolean big) throws IOException {
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog;
    PDAcroForm acroForm;
    PDField field;
    COSDictionary dict;
    COSString defaultAppearance;
    
    docCatalog = pdfTemplate.getDocumentCatalog();
    acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    field = acroForm.getField(fieldName);
    dict = field.getDictionary();
    
    defaultAppearance = (COSString) dict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.DA);
    if (defaultAppearance != null) {
        if (big) {
            dict.setString(COSName.DA, "/" + fontName + " 16.17 Tf 0 g");
        } else {
            dict.setString(COSName.DA, "/" + fontName + " 8.67 Tf 0 g");
        }
        if (field instanceof PDTextbox) {
            field = new PDTextbox(acroForm, dict);
            field.setValue(content);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what other info could be useful, but I'm ready to provide anything I'm asked about.

Comment: Try with 2.0.25, lots of improvements in acroform there.

Comment: Please be aware that some details on the form field appearance generation are not clearly specified and, therefore, up to the generator. Nonetheless, PDFBox attempts to emulate Adobe Acrobat behavior and got better version by version. So updating from your ancient version to a current one is indeed a very good idea.

Comment: Thanks guys, I’ll have a try. I’ll let the question open in the meantime, and I will eventually post the result.